# DataDynamics ActiveReports is not printing the page footer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, printing, preview, activereports

I am using DataDynamics ActiveReport to generate a report. When I run the program and generate the report everything looks fine. Yet when I print the report the page footer isn't printed. What is going wrong and how do I fix this?

EDIT:  In case this is needed I am creating an 11x17 report in landscape mode. I am able to export this to a pdf (which has the page footer showing up) and then print. The resulting printout has the footer but cuts off the page. If I print this to a printer on the network or with my document writer the page footer does not show up. To make this more complicated when I added a page header the page header prints, just not the footer.

EDIT: A friend printed off here 11x17 ActiveReport off as well and she had the same problem. If it was just the printer and not the document writer I would assume it was because we are printing it on two sheets as we don't have 11x17 paper, but the same problem happens when we print it to a .tif file.

If it helps I set the page settings within ReportStart:

```
Me.PageSettings.PaperKind = Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.Standard11x17
Me.Document.Printer.PrinterName = ""
Me.PageSettings.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
Me.PageSettings.Margins.Top = 0.25
Me.PageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0.25
Me.PageSettings.Margins.Left = 0.25
Me.PageSettings.Margins.Right = 0.25
```

And I set the print width, within the properties of the report, to 16.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologize for the inconvenience.  I have asked the ActiveReports team to investigate what is going on.  I will update as soon  as I have an answer.  In the meantime, do u have a sample report or a working project that you can email us?  That will definitely help in finding ou what is going on.  You can always email support@grapecity.us.com if you have any ActiveReports related questions.

thanks

raji

Comment: Sorry I don't have a sample report and I can't sent the working project. It did happen on two different projects though so it has to be more universal.

Comment: Kyra,

Thanks for the update and the code snippet.  I will run this through the AR team and get to the bottom of this.

thanks

raji

Comment: update:
Kyra, Is there a reason why you cant set the paper size to one available or let AR API get the sizes available from the printer?

We have entered a case 149141 to review this issue further.  Current suggestion is to set the page size to a value which is supported on the printer.

Please email support@grapecity.us.com to inquire about the case in future.